# visibility of labels based on equality of a Calender date and the array of intervals of 2 dates

Tags: java, date

i am trying to display labels based on the date which picked from calender .
From and To dates are taken from database and the dates between them has calculated ..its all working fine ..but i am not getting the visibility by checking  equality of interval  with calender date picking ..please help me out..here is my code

```
    package javaapplication91;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

import java.text.DateFormat;

import java.text.ParseException;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Date;

import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JavaApplication91 implements MouseListener {



static String driverName = "org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver";
 String url = "jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:\\DOCTORSMASTERTABLE.GDB";

 String userName = "SYSDBA";

 String password = "masterkey";

 Connection connect;

 ResultSet rs;

 Statement st;

 String qry,ran;

 List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();

 DateFormat formatter;

 JTextField[][] lb = new JTextField[1000][500];

 JFrame prnt = new JFrame();

 JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));

 JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));

 JLabel l = new JLabel();

 int in,i,k;

public JavaApplication91() throws IOException {

    prnt.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

    p1.setBackground(Color.red);

    l.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    l.setBackground(Color.black);

    l.setText("clik");

    l.addMouseListener(this);

            p1.add(l);

}

public void ctr() throws ParseException, SQLException {

        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        st = connect.createStatement();

        qry="SELECT \"AVAIL FROM_DATE\",\"AVAIL TO_DATE\",D_NAME FROM DOCTOR_DETAILS;";

        rs = st.executeQuery(qry);

        prnt.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
         in = 0;

         java.sql.Date  ran;

         java.sql.Date ran1;

         while(rs.next()){

             ran = rs.getDate(1);

             ran1 = rs.getDate(2);

             String name = rs.getString(3);

    long interval = 24 * 1000 * 60 * 60; 

    long endTime = ran1.getTime(); 

    long curTime = ran.getTime();

    while (curTime <= endTime) {

        dates.add(new Date(curTime));

        curTime += interval;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {

        Date lDate = (Date) dates.get(i);

        String ds = formatter.format(lDate);

        lb[in][i] = new JTextField();

        lb[in][i].setText(""+ds);

        lb[in][i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));

        p.add(lb[in][i]);

        //lb[i].setVisible(false);

         System.out.println(" Date is ..." + ds);    
    }
    dates.clear();

    in++;

    }prnt.add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    prnt.add(p1,BorderLayout.EAST);

    prnt.pack();

    prnt.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException, SQLException {
    new JavaApplication91().ctr();

}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

   if(e.getComponent() == l){

   JavaApplication89 d = new JavaApplication89(prnt); 

   l.setText(d.setPickedDate());

   for(int k = 0; k < in;k++){

       for(int m = 0; m<i ; m++){

       if(lb[k][m] != null){

       if(lb[k][m].getText().equals(d.setPickedDate())){

           dates.clear();

           lb[k][m].setVisible(true);

       }else{

           lb[k][m].hide(); 
       }       
       }
       }
       } 
   } 
}
@Override

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 

}

@Override

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

  //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.



 }

@Override

public void (mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {


//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

 }

@Override

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

 //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

the problem is at the mouse click if condition

class that provides setPickDate is

```
package javaapplication91;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JDialog;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JavaApplication89 {
    JLabel l1;
int month = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);

int year = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);

//JLabel l = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER) ;

String day = "";
JDialog d;

JButton[] button = new JButton[49];

    Random rm = new Random();

public JavaApplication89(JFrame parent) {

        d = new JDialog();

    d.setModal(true);

            System.out.println("mnth " + month);

            l1 = new JLabel();

            l1.setText("Year : "+String.valueOf(year)+"   Month:"+String.valueOf(month) );
            l1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));

    String[] header = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat" };

    final JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7, 7));

    p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));

    for (int x = 0; x < button.length; x++) {

        final int selection = x;

        button[x] = new JButton();

        button[x].setFocusPainted(false);

        button[x].setBackground(Color.white);

        if (x > 6)

            button[x].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                                    @Override

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                    day = button[selection].getActionCommand();

                                            d.dispose();
                }
            });

        if (x < 7) {

            button[x].setText(header[x]);

            button[x].setForeground(Color.red);
        }

                    d.add(l1,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        p1.add(button[x]);

                    }

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 3));

    JButton previous = new JButton("<< Previous");

    previous.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            month--;

                            displayDate();

                            l1.setText( "Year :" + year +"  month : "+month);
        }
    });

    p2.add(previous);

    JButton next = new JButton("Next >>");

            JButton raa = new JButton("Time Choose from here");

            raa.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    e.getSource();

                    JFrame fm = new JFrame("time Picker");

                    fm.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

                    JLabel lb = new JLabel();

                    fm.add(lb, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                    fm.pack();

                    fm.setVisible(true);//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }
            });
                next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            month++;

            displayDate();

                            l1.setText( "Year :" + year +"  month : "+month);
        }
    });

            p2.add(next);

            d.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    d.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    d.pack();

    d.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);

    displayDate();

    d.setVisible(true);
}
public void displayDate() {

    for (int x = 7; x < button.length; x++)

        button[x].setText("");

    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(

            "mmm hhh");

    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(year, month, 1);

    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    int daysInMonth = cal.getActualMaximum(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    for (int x = 6 + dayOfWeek, day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; x++, day++)

        button[x].setText("" + day);

    //l.setText(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

    d.setTitle("Date Picker");
}
public String setPickedDate() {

    if (day.equals(""))

        return day;

    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(

            "dd/MM/yyyy");

    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(year, month, Integer.parseInt(day));

    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Selected Date:");

    final JTextField text = new JTextField(20);

            JButton b = new JButton("popup");

    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    p.add(label);

    p.add(text);

    p.add(b);

    final JFrame f = new JFrame();

            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    f.getContentPane().add(p);

    f.pack();

    f.setVisible(true);

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            text.setText(new JavaApplication89(f).setPickedDate());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. You've got a blank line between every single line of text, making it *very* hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(lb[m].equals(d.setPickedDate()))
```

should probably be:

```
if(lb[k][m].equals(d.setPickedDate()))
```

edit: on further inspection, even this sounds unlikely (...unless `d.setPickedDate()` returns a `JTextField`). Make sure you are comparing the actual objects you want to compare, and that they are instances of the same class.

Comment: then: what is the type of d.setPickedDate()? I doubt it is an array of `JTextField`.

Comment: You are using equals(...) to compare an array of JTextField to a String. This is where the problem is. Make sure you are comparing the return value of this d.setPickedDate() to another String (and most likely, you will want to use `equalsIgnoreCase(...)`).

Comment: thank u a million for ur comments..but still i am fed up with it..i have called JTextField's getText() for equality..yet it looks like before..:(

Comment: One final suggestion; make sure that the output of `getText()` is in the exact same format as your `d.setPickedDate()`.